# Pause/stop Sink consuming from topic in Kafka Connect Transformer

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I've created a transformer that does some transformations on a `ConnectRecord` to be used in a Kafka Connect worker.

The Transformer works ok, but I want it to stop the sink from consuming messages on a specific topic when a certain criteria (error) is found.

Momentarily the code throws an exception, grinding the worker to a halt. Although its effectiveness, this potentially also influences other topics and seems like a last resort.

Is there a way to stop/pause the consuming of a topic from the Kafka Connect `Transformation` code in a nice way?

```
class ApplySchemaTransformation[T <: ConnectRecord[T]]
    extends Transformation[T]
    with ContentTypeHandler[T] {

   override def apply(record: T): T = {
     if ([some criteria]) {
       [ok code]
     } else {
       [stop consumer]
     }
   }

   override def config(): ConfigDef = ...

   override def close(): Unit = {}

   override def configure(configs: java.util.Map[String, _]): Unit = ...
}
```

Comment: Could you explain the "other topics" thing? If `topics` or `topics.regex` only matches one topic, then the transform only affects one topic, not others

Comment: Yes indeed. But if I throw an exception in the transformer it brings down the entire Connect Worker influencing other topics (due to the regex configuration it also handles other topics on that worker)

Comment: Hmm. I don't think it should... It'll cause a rebalance of all the workers, but not stop other connectors running with other `topics.regex` values

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Ok. Maybe something else is going on :-/ So you'd say that throwing an exception would be the best way for a connect worker to stop consuming from that topic?

Comment: I think so... Haven't done it myself, but you could also do `http://localhost:8083/connectors/{name}/pause`

Comment: Yep pause works (thanks) - needs to be a PUT.